# Adding jQuery animation prevents my remove button from working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-animate

I am making a todo list webapp with jQuery. I have a remove button that removes an entire row in a table. I got it to work just fine but once I put in an animation for the remove button it no longer works. What I want to happen is the user clicks the remove button, an animation in the button happens, and then the row gets removed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
$("table").on("click", ".btn-danger", function() {
  var fire = $("<span>").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-fire").attr("aria-hidden", "true").fadeIn(1000);
  $(this).replaceWith($("<button>").attr("type", "button").addClass("btn btn-danger btn-width").append(fire));
  $(this).parent().parent().remove(); // Remove entire row
});
```

Comment: You are removing grand parent so your appended element is removed too. What exactly is your issue? `it no longer works` Do you mean the row isn't removed?  If you want to remove grand parent once animation is done, use relevant animate() callback.  Anyway you have to provide MCVE

Comment: Yes, the row is not removed. The animation happens but nothing else.

Comment: Ok but using replaceWith(), element isn't anymore in the DOM so `parent()` returns empty object. Cache grand parent before replacing element. But again then, removing it doesn't make sense as this will remove your appended element too... FYI, instead of `parent().parent()` use `closest(selector)`.

Comment: how you replaceWith and append  and after that remove the parent?? @A.Wolff  absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are setting the `fadeIn`, before it's added to the DOM, so it wont work properly.

On the other hand, jquery animations runs asynchronously, so you run the `fadeIn`, but just after it, you remove the parent.

I would do it like this:

```
$("table").on("click", ".btn-danger", function() {
    var fire = $("<span>").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-fire").attr("aria-hidden", "true")
    $(this).replaceWith($("<button>").attr("type", "button").addClass("btn btn-danger btn-width").append(fire));
    var instance = this;
    fire.fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $(instance).parent().parent().remove(); // Remove entire row
    });
});
```

If you look at my code, I run the `fadeIn` after it is appended, and I use the second parameter of the fadeIn, which is a callback after the 1000 milliseconds, so the parent will be removed after the animation is finished.

Comment: I just tried this but now it skips the animation and deletes the row immediately. Not sure why this is the case.

Comment: Also, why use the `var instance = this;`? What's wrong with just using `this`?

Comment: If it just removes inmediately, maybe you are creating wrong the DOM Element, could yo paste an example in a js Fiddle, so I can checkout what is wring?

-- The `var instance = this` is because in the callback, you are inside another function, so this changes it value, so `instance` is the value of this, out of the function, which is the value you need

Comment: Or maybe if `fire` element is already visible, you wont see any effect.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle. I appreciate the help.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrmendonez/bogwckdn/2/

Comment: Please check out this update, I guess this is what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/bogwckdn/3/
The only thing I changed is to hide the button before trigger the animation, otherwise, you wont see the effect, since the image is already visible

`fire.hide();`

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you =)